# How can I find the center of the circle or ellipse I just created

Tags: qgis, centroids, circle

I need to draw circles and ellipses with a certain length/width/ radius.
I used the rectangles ovals digitizing plugin to create them, but only measured roughly the circles' radiuses. It would be great if somebody knew how to do this more exact.
what would also be good to know: is there a possibility, if I create a bigger and a smaller circle, to let the smaller circle snap to the bigger circle's center?

**But the most important question is: 
if I already have the circles I need, how can I make their exact center visible, so I can create my ellipses from exactly the same starting point?**

I hope for help!!

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73362/how-to-efficiently-determine-if-a-collection-of-coordinates-polygon-is-an-elli

Comment: is a "circles" center the same as its x,y centroid? I suppose so as long as you have been diligent with the vertices.

Comment: If you know the shape is circular, then the mid-point between any two opposite vertices [0 & (N-1)/2, 1 & (N+1)/2,...] is also the center.